# Content Search webpart not displaying results

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-search-web-part

The content search web part is not showing the results in the page, however I see the results when I test the query:

```
(IsDocument:"True") Path:{SiteCollection.URL} NOT FileExtension:aspx NOT FileExtension:one
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the webpart show any display template error?

Comment: No, any error in the webpart just not displaying the results

Comment: FileExtension:one . What is this for? What documents are you trying to exclude

Comment: Extension one is trying to remove the oneNote files but That's not the problem, if i remove that part of the query still doesn't work.

Comment: Try this . (IsDocument:"True") AND  Path:{SiteCollection.URL} AND  -FileExtension:aspx AND  -FileExtension:one

Comment: Same: Nothing... I think that the problem is not related to the query

Comment: In the web part properties, are the 2 options: "display ranked" and "display promoted results" checked?

Comment: I'm not seeing those properties in the webpart

Comment: If you configure your webpart to show all results, does it return something or it's still empty ?

Comment: It's still empty